# Condição simples não funciona

Tags: if, condição, else

Olá, pessoal. Estou BEM no início e tenho uma dúvida sobre uma condição simples.

Basicamente, o usuário digita duas notas e a média é 5. Se a média for maior do que 5, exibe um alert  de "Aprovado", senão, um alert de "Reprovado". Fiz o código abaixo, mas mesmo digitando notas com média abaixo de 5, sempre aparece "Aprovado". Alguém pode me ajudar, por favor?
Muito obrigado.

```
<script>
var nota1 = prompt("Digite sua nota");
var nota2 = prompt("Digite sua nota");
var media = (nota1 + nota2) / 2;

if(media > 5) {
    alert("Aprovado");
} 
else {
    alert("Reprovado");
}
</script>
```

Comment: [prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/window/prompt) retorna uma string (texto), para fazer operações matemáticas você tem que converter para inteiro com [parseInt(nota)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) ou float com [parseFloat(nota)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

Comment: Ilustrando o que o @Benilson descreveu, quando vc entra por exemplo 1 e 1 a nota fica 11.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá, Juan!
Como o Muniz comentou, está ocorrendo erro de concatenação de strings (como se fossem agrupamentos de texto, que ocorrem ao usar o sinal de adição em strings) ao invés da operação de adição em si.

Além disso, é importante atentar que esse tipo de regra para aprovação/reprovação utiliza operadores de comparação e, nesse caso, se o aluno tirar exatamente 5 ele já seria aprovado. Portanto, o operador a ser usado é o ">=" (maior ou igual a) e não ">" (maior), pois o uso do ">" faz com que o aluno que tirou nota "5" seja reprovado.

Coloco abaixo o código corrigido de uma forma simples para:

- transformar as strings dos prompts em numbers;
- alterar a regra de aprovação;

```js
var nota1 = prompt("Digite sua nota");
var nota2 = prompt("Digite sua nota");

nota1 = Number(nota1);
nota2 = Number(nota2);

var media = (nota1 + nota2) / 2;

if(media >= 5) {
    alert("Aprovado");
} 
else {
    alert("Reprovado");
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score -2):

Não sei a linguagem utilizada, mas no python fiz algumas correções e deu certo:

nota1 = int(input("Digite sua nota"));

nota2 = int(input("Digite sua nota"));

media = (nota1 + nota2) / 2;

if(media > 5):

```
print("Aprovado")
```

else:

```
print("Reprovado");
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score -2):

O problema no seu código está relacionado ao fato de que prompt retorna strings, e ao tentar calcular a média diretamente, você está concatenando strings em vez de realizar a operação de adição.

Você precisa converter as notas de strings para números (números inteiros ou de ponto flutuante) antes de calcular a média. Isso pode ser feito usando a função parseFloat para converter as strings em números decimais. Aqui está uma versão corrigida do seu código:

```
<script>
var nota1 = prompt("Digite sua nota 1");
var nota2 = prompt("Digite sua nota 2");

// Convertendo as notas de strings para números decimais
var nota1Numero = parseFloat(nota1);
var nota2Numero = parseFloat(nota2);

// Calculando a média
var media = (nota1Numero + nota2Numero) / 2;

// Verificando se a média é maior que 5
if (media > 5) {
    alert("Aprovado");
} else {
    alert("Reprovado");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!